# Deploying python code with H2O algorithms directly in production without MOJO and POJO

Tags: python, machine-learning, licensing, h2o

I am planning to use H2O algorithms in my product.

The product is developed in python and uses majorly pandas, sklearn and H2O.

Can I deploy my python code with H2O algorithms in python directly? Or do I need to use MOJO or POJO ?

Comment: Please visit the docs for these types of questions: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/index.html and H2O User Guide: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/index.html

Comment: @Machavity This isn't asking licensing advice. It is about which of two APIs can (technically) be used in production; either way the h2o part is under Apache license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save and load models in python directly, although this will require you to have h2o running

https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/10/docs-website/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps.

Comment: This is the same link, but release agnostic:  http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html

Answer (score 1):

The skutil project might be helpful for you.  It's an integration of scikit-learn and H2O.

See:

https://github.com/tgsmith61591/skutil